# Finding Monthly Intervals

Tags: sql, excel, excel-2007, sas, excel-formula

My work entails that I have to calculate 6 thru 18 months back from a specific date. I have 2 examples.
Example 1: 
My work asks me to calculate refunds from our clients.  These refunds can only be 18 months at a time and the last date of the refund period is the day the letter goes out to the client.  So, If the refund letter is set to be sent on August 28, 2012, What is the first date of that period? Also, what if it were August 29, 30, and 31st(08/28/2012 - 08/31/2012). My calculation would say that all of these time periods have March 1st, 2011 as their start date.  I use SAS as the program tool. Here is the function I used:

```
 eighteen_months = intnx('month',Visit_date,18,'sameday')+1;
```

The main assumption that I am making is 1 month is equal to the first date of the first month and the last date and that same month(01/01/2012 thru 01/31/2012). Subsequently, 3 months is equal to the first date of the first month and the last date of the 3rd month(01/01/2012 thru 03/31/2012 or 04/01/2012 thru 06/30/2012).  Here are a couple of other 18 month Calculations:

```
                First Date           Last Date
                10/30/1999           4/29/2001
                 5/6/2006            11/5/2007
                4/30/2012           10/29/2013
                 4/3/2018            10/2/2019
                  2/24/2024          8/23/2025
                  5/10/2026          11/9/2027
```

The issue occurs in the case of my original example with August 28-31 where 18months can actually be 4 different time lengths.

Example 2:
My work also asks me to do the opposite where I have the first date and need figure out a  6 thru 18 month time period.  I was recently asked what is 6 months if the first date is 06/22/2012? I responded with 12/21/2012 and was told that it is actually 12/22/2012.  There is no real documentation/logic on how this is calculated in the company. Here is my function in SAS.

```
    Six_months = intnx('month',Visit_date,6,'sameday')-1;
```

I am trying to establish a process and wanted to see if anyone runs into these processes on a consistent basis and if there is any easier way in Excel/SAS.  Any responses would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If this is a question about Excel and SAS, why do you have the SQL tag on it?

Comment: My DB tool where I pull data from is Teradata.  If there is any way to do this in there or ANSI standard sql that would also be beneficial.  Sorry for the confusion...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the First Date from Last Date in Excel try this formula where Last Date is in B2

`=EDATE(B2,-18)+1`

That works for your 6 listed examples and also works to return 1st March 2011 from 28/29/30/31 August 2012

EDATE function, as you might guess, can be used to add or subtract a number of months from a date, if the day doesn't exist within that month, like 30th Feb, then it defaults to the last day of that month

Comment: Using this function, I yield the same results, Thanks! I guess my main question was to see if there was a standard way of establishing what 6 or 18 months is or if there was a statute of some sort.  Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Many databases support the function `add_months` or `dateadd` or something similar (including Teradata).  To get the date 18 months earlier or later, you would do something like:

```
select add_months(LastDate, -18), LastDate
```

I think that answers the *before* question.  The answer question is a little bit trickier, since there are multiple dates.  You can get the first and last such dates with the following trick:

```
select add_months(FirstDate, 18) as LastDate1,
       add_months(FirstDate+1, 18) - 1 as LastDate2
```

That is, add_months returns the first day that matches the condition of being 18 months in the future (I'm pretty sure of this but not 100% positive for Teradata).  The second date is one day before 18 months after the next day.  Normally it will be the same as for the first date, but not always.

Comment: So in this case, I am using the SQL environment within SAS and there is not an add_months function in the software, unfortunately but will look through to see if there is something similar. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The SAS `INTNX` function is quite equivalent to the Teradata `ADD_MONTHS` function and is much more flexible.  You can specify any interval you want and any offset alignment.  I read your question as about date manipulation processes.  If you have a particular usage problem, ask another and provide some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

This is the brute force way from Lorin and Dan

```
%MACRO DATES(YEAR, lib);
data post.try&lib.; set post.pact;
IF DTE_EFFECTIVE LE &year. LE DTE_END  THEN DO ELIGMONTH= &year.; FORMAT ELIGMONTH MMDDYY10.; OUTPUT post.TRY&lib.;  END;
run;
%MEND;
%DATES (YEAR='01JAN2000'D, LIB=a)
%DATES (YEAR='01FEB2000'D, LIB=b)
%DATES (YEAR='01MAR2000'D, LIB=c)
%DATES (YEAR='01APR2000'D, LIB=d)
%DATES (YEAR='01MAY2000'D, LIB=e)
%DATES (YEAR='01JUN2000'D, LIB=f)
%DATES (YEAR='01JUL2000'D, LIB=g)
%DATES (YEAR='01AUG2000'D, LIB=h)
%DATES (YEAR='01SEP2000'D, LIB=i)
%DATES (YEAR='01OCT2000'D, LIB=j)
%DATES (YEAR='01NOV2000'D, LIB=k)
%DATES (YEAR='01DEC2000'D, LIB=l)
%DATES (YEAR='01JAN2001'D, LIB=m)
%DATES (YEAR='01FEB2001'D, LIB=n)
%DATES (YEAR='01MAR2001'D, LIB=o)
%DATES (YEAR='01APR2001'D, LIB=p)
%DATES (YEAR='01MAY2001'D, LIB=q)
%DATES (YEAR='01JUN2001'D, LIB=r)
%DATES (YEAR='01JUL2001'D, LIB=s)
%DATES (YEAR='01AUG2001'D, LIB=t)
%DATES (YEAR='01SEP2001'D, LIB=u)
%DATES (YEAR='01OCT2001'D, LIB=v)
%DATES (YEAR='01NOV2001'D, LIB=w)
%DATES (YEAR='01DEC2001'D, LIB=x)
%DATES (YEAR='01JAN2002'D, LIB=y)
%DATES (YEAR='01FEB2002'D, LIB=z)
%DATES (YEAR='01MAR2002'D, LIB=aa)
%DATES (YEAR='01APR2002'D, LIB=bb)
%DATES (YEAR='01MAY2002'D, LIB=cc)
%DATES (YEAR='01JUN2002'D, LIB=dd)
%DATES (YEAR='01JUL2002'D, LIB=ee)
%DATES (YEAR='01AUG2002'D, LIB=ff)
%DATES (YEAR='01SEP2002'D, LIB=gg)
%DATES (YEAR='01OCT2002'D, LIB=hh)
%DATES (YEAR='01NOV2002'D, LIB=ii)
%DATES (YEAR='01DEC2002'D, LIB=jj)
%DATES (YEAR='01JAN2003'D, LIB=kk)
%DATES (YEAR='01FEB2003'D, LIB=ll)
%DATES (YEAR='01MAR2003'D, LIB=mm)
%DATES (YEAR='01APR2003'D, LIB=nn)
%DATES (YEAR='01MAY2003'D, LIB=oo)
%DATES (YEAR='01JUN2003'D, LIB=pp)
%DATES (YEAR='01JUL2003'D, LIB=qq)
%DATES (YEAR='01AUG2003'D, LIB=rr)
%DATES (YEAR='01SEP2003'D, LIB=ss)
%DATES (YEAR='01OCT2003'D, LIB=tt)
%DATES (YEAR='01NOV2003'D, LIB=uu)
%DATES (YEAR='01DEC2003'D, LIB=vv)
%DATES (YEAR='01JAN2004'D, LIB=ww)
%DATES (YEAR='01FEB2004'D, LIB=xx)
%DATES (YEAR='01MAR2004'D, LIB=yy)
%DATES (YEAR='01APR2004'D, LIB=zz)
%DATES (YEAR='01MAY2004'D, LIB=aa)
%DATES (YEAR='01JUN2004'D, LIB=bb)
%DATES (YEAR='01JUL2004'D, LIB=cc)
%DATES (YEAR='01AUG2004'D, LIB=dd)
%DATES (YEAR='01SEP2004'D, LIB=ee)
%DATES (YEAR='01OCT2004'D, LIB=ff)
%DATES (YEAR='01NOV2004'D, LIB=gg)
%DATES (YEAR='01DEC2004'D, LIB=hh)
%DATES (YEAR='01JAN2005'D, LIB=ii)
%DATES (YEAR='01FEB2005'D, LIB=jj)
%DATES (YEAR='01MAR2005'D, LIB=kk)
%DATES (YEAR='01APR2005'D, LIB=ll)
%DATES (YEAR='01MAY2005'D, LIB=mm)
%DATES (YEAR='01JUN2005'D, LIB=nn)
%DATES (YEAR='01JUL2005'D, LIB=oo)
%DATES (YEAR='01AUG2005'D, LIB=pp)
%DATES (YEAR='01SEP2005'D, LIB=qq)
%DATES (YEAR='01OCT2005'D, LIB=rr)
%DATES (YEAR='01NOV2005'D, LIB=ss)
%DATES (YEAR='01DEC2005'D, LIB=tt)
%DATES (YEAR='01JAN2006'D, LIB=uu)
%DATES (YEAR='01FEB2006'D, LIB=vv)
%DATES (YEAR='01MAR2006'D, LIB=ww)
%DATES (YEAR='01APR2006'D, LIB=xx)
%DATES (YEAR='01MAY2006'D, LIB=yy)
%DATES (YEAR='01JUN2006'D, LIB=zz)
%DATES (YEAR='01JUL2006'D, LIB=aaa)
%DATES (YEAR='01AUG2006'D, LIB=bbb)
%DATES (YEAR='01SEP2006'D, LIB=ccc)
%DATES (YEAR='01OCT2006'D, LIB=ddd)
%DATES (YEAR='01NOV2006'D, LIB=eee)
%DATES (YEAR='01DEC2006'D, LIB=fff)
%DATES (YEAR='01JAN2007'D, LIB=ggg)
%DATES (YEAR='01FEB2007'D, LIB=hhh)
%DATES (YEAR='01MAR2007'D, LIB=iii)
%DATES (YEAR='01APR2007'D, LIB=jjj)
%DATES (YEAR='01MAY2007'D, LIB=kkk)
%DATES (YEAR='01JUN2007'D, LIB=lll)
%DATES (YEAR='01JUL2007'D, LIB=mmm)
%DATES (YEAR='01AUG2007'D, LIB=nnn)
%DATES (YEAR='01SEP2007'D, LIB=ooo)
%DATES (YEAR='01OCT2007'D, LIB=ppp)
%DATES (YEAR='01NOV2007'D, LIB=qqq)
%DATES (YEAR='01DEC2007'D, LIB=rrr)
%DATES (YEAR='01JAN2008'D, LIB=sss)
%DATES (YEAR='01FEB2008'D, LIB=ttt)
%DATES (YEAR='01MAR2008'D, LIB=uuu)
%DATES (YEAR='01APR2008'D, LIB=vvv)
%DATES (YEAR='01MAY2008'D, LIB=www)
%DATES (YEAR='01JUN2008'D, LIB=xxx)
%DATES (YEAR='01JUL2008'D, LIB=yyy)
%DATES (YEAR='01AUG2008'D, LIB=zzz)
%DATES (YEAR='01SEP2008'D, LIB=aaaa)
%DATES (YEAR='01OCT2008'D, LIB=bbbb)
%DATES (YEAR='01NOV2008'D, LIB=cccc)
%DATES (YEAR='01DEC2008'D, LIB=dddd)
%DATES (YEAR='01JAN2009'D, LIB=eeee)
%DATES (YEAR='01FEB2009'D, LIB=ffff)
%DATES (YEAR='01MAR2009'D, LIB=gggg)
%DATES (YEAR='01APR2009'D, LIB=hhhh)
%DATES (YEAR='01MAY2009'D, LIB=iiii)
%DATES (YEAR='01JUN2009'D, LIB=jjjj)
%DATES (YEAR='01JUL2009'D, LIB=kkkk)
%DATES (YEAR='01AUG2009'D, LIB=llll)
%DATES (YEAR='01SEP2009'D, LIB=mmmm)
%DATES (YEAR='01OCT2009'D, LIB=nnnn)
%DATES (YEAR='01NOV2009'D, LIB=oooo)
%DATES (YEAR='01DEC2009'D, LIB=pppp)
%DATES (YEAR='01JAN2010'D, LIB=qqqq)
%DATES (YEAR='01FEB2010'D, LIB=rrrr)
%DATES (YEAR='01MAR2010'D, LIB=ssss)
%DATES (YEAR='01APR2010'D, LIB=tttt)
%DATES (YEAR='01MAY2010'D, LIB=uuuu)
%DATES (YEAR='01JUN2010'D, LIB=vvvv)
%DATES (YEAR='01JUL2010'D, LIB=wwww)
%DATES (YEAR='01AUG2010'D, LIB=xxxx)
%DATES (YEAR='01SEP2010'D, LIB=yyyy)
%DATES (YEAR='01OCT2010'D, LIB=zzzz)
%DATES (YEAR='01NOV2010'D, LIB=aaaaa)
%DATES (YEAR='01DEC2010'D, LIB=bbbbb)
%DATES (YEAR='01JAN2011'D, LIB=ccccc)
%DATES (YEAR='01FEB2011'D, LIB=ddddd)
%DATES (YEAR='01MAR2011'D, LIB=eeeee)
%DATES (YEAR='01APR2011'D, LIB=fffff)
%DATES (YEAR='01MAY2011'D, LIB=ggggg)
%DATES (YEAR='01JUN2011'D, LIB=hhhhh)
%DATES (YEAR='01JUL2011'D, LIB=iiiii)
%DATES (YEAR='01AUG2011'D, LIB=jjjjj)
%DATES (YEAR='01SEP2011'D, LIB=kkkkk)
%DATES (YEAR='01OCT2011'D, LIB=lllll)
%DATES (YEAR='01NOV2011'D, LIB=mmmmm)
%DATES (YEAR='01DEC2011'D, LIB=nnnnn)
%DATES (YEAR='01JAN2012'D, LIB=ooooo)
%DATES (YEAR='01FEB2012'D, LIB=ppppp)
%DATES (YEAR='01MAR2012'D, LIB=qqqqq)
%DATES (YEAR='01APR2012'D, LIB=rrrrr)
%DATES (YEAR='01MAY2012'D, LIB=sssss)
%DATES (YEAR='01JUN2012'D, LIB=ttttt)
%DATES (YEAR='01JUL2012'D, LIB=uuuuu)
%DATES (YEAR='01AUG2012'D, LIB=vvvvv)
%DATES (YEAR='01SEP2012'D, LIB=wwwww)
%DATES (YEAR='01OCT2012'D, LIB=xxxxx)
%DATES (YEAR='01NOV2012'D, LIB=yyyyy)
%DATES (YEAR='01DEC2012'D, LIB=zzzzz)
%DATES (YEAR='01JAN2013'D, LIB=aaaaaa)
%DATES (YEAR='01FEB2013'D, LIB=bbbbbb)
%DATES (YEAR='01MAR2013'D, LIB=cccccc)
%DATES (YEAR='01APR2013'D, LIB=dddddd)
%DATES (YEAR='01MAY2013'D, LIB=eeeeee)
%DATES (YEAR='01JUN2013'D, LIB=ffffff)
%DATES (YEAR='01JUL2013'D, LIB=gggggg)
%DATES (YEAR='01AUG2013'D, LIB=hhhhhh)
%DATES (YEAR='01SEP2013'D, LIB=iiiiii)
%DATES (YEAR='01OCT2013'D, LIB=jjjjjj)
%DATES (YEAR='01NOV2013'D, LIB=kkkkkk)
%DATES (YEAR='01DEC2013'D, LIB=llllll)




data post.final; set post.TRYa
post.TRYb
post.TRYc
post.TRYd
post.TRYe
post.TRYf
post.TRYg
post.TRYh
post.TRYi
post.TRYj
post.TRYk
post.TRYl
post.TRYm
post.TRYn
post.TRYo
post.TRYp
post.TRYq
post.TRYr
post.TRYs
post.TRYt
post.TRYu
post.TRYv
post.TRYw
post.TRYx
post.TRYy
post.TRYz
post.TRYaa
post.TRYbb
post.TRYcc
post.TRYdd
post.TRYee
post.TRYff
post.TRYgg
post.TRYhh
post.TRYii
post.TRYjj
post.TRYkk
post.TRYll
post.TRYmm
post.TRYnn
post.TRYoo
post.TRYpp
post.TRYqq
post.TRYrr
post.TRYss
post.TRYtt
post.TRYuu
post.TRYvv
post.TRYww
post.TRYxx
post.TRYyy
post.TRYzz
post.TRYaa
post.TRYbb
post.TRYcc
post.TRYdd
post.TRYee
post.TRYff
post.TRYgg
post.TRYhh
post.TRYii
post.TRYjj
post.TRYkk
post.TRYll
post.TRYmm
post.TRYnn
post.TRYoo
post.TRYpp
post.TRYqq
post.TRYrr
post.TRYss
post.TRYtt
post.TRYuu
post.TRYvv
post.TRYww
post.TRYxx
post.TRYyy
post.TRYzz
post.TRYaaa
post.TRYbbb
post.TRYccc
post.TRYddd
post.TRYeee
post.TRYfff
post.TRYggg
post.TRYhhh
post.TRYiii
post.TRYjjj
post.TRYkkk
post.TRYlll
post.TRYmmm
post.TRYnnn
post.TRYooo
post.TRYppp
post.TRYqqq
post.TRYrrr
post.TRYsss
post.TRYttt
post.TRYuuu
post.TRYvvv
post.TRYwww
post.TRYxxx
post.TRYyyy
post.TRYzzz
post.TRYaaaa
post.TRYbbbb
post.TRYcccc
post.TRYdddd
post.TRYeeee
post.TRYffff
post.TRYgggg
post.TRYhhhh
post.TRYiiii
post.TRYjjjj
post.TRYkkkk
post.TRYllll
post.TRYmmmm
post.TRYnnnn
post.TRYoooo
post.TRYpppp
post.TRYqqqq
post.TRYrrrr
post.TRYssss
post.TRYtttt
post.TRYuuuu
post.TRYvvvv
post.TRYwwww
post.TRYxxxx
post.TRYyyyy
post.TRYzzzz
post.TRYaaaaa
post.TRYbbbbb
post.TRYccccc
post.TRYddddd
post.TRYeeeee
post.TRYfffff
post.TRYggggg
post.TRYhhhhh
post.TRYiiiii
post.TRYjjjjj
post.TRYkkkkk
post.TRYlllll
post.TRYmmmmm
post.TRYnnnnn
post.TRYooooo
post.TRYppppp
post.TRYqqqqq
post.TRYrrrrr
post.TRYsssss
post.TRYttttt
post.TRYuuuuu
post.TRYvvvvv
post.TRYwwwww
post.TRYxxxxx
post.TRYyyyyy
post.TRYzzzzz
post.TRYaaaaaa
post.TRYbbbbbb
post.TRYcccccc
post.TRYdddddd
post.TRYeeeeee
post.TRYffffff
post.TRYgggggg
post.TRYhhhhhh
post.TRYiiiiii
post.TRYjjjjjj
post.TRYkkkkkk
post.TRYllllll
;run;
```